# Padding overflow of anchor elements <a>

Tags: html, css

I think a screenshot describes the issue the best:

[image: padding problem]

As you can see, the paddings "merge" into each other, but only vertically. Horizontally the padding is as expected (i.e. between **Start** and **Leistungen**). Why is there not more space between the header **Physiotherapie**, the middle line (**Start Leistungen Kon**) and **Impressum**?.

```css
header #title {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

header nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

header nav a {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a id="title" href="index.html">Physiotherapie</a>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html">Start</a>
    <a href="">Leistungen</a>
    <a href="">Kontakt</a>
    <a href="">Anfahrt</a>
    <a href="">Impressum</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

P.S.: I'm using default box-sizing (content-box), but also if I use border-box, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vertical padding is ignored for inline elements.
Solution: turn them into `inline-block`s, then the padding will have an effect.

```css
header #title {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

header nav {
    display: inline-block;
}

header nav a {
    display:inline-block; /* added */
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <a id="title" href="index.html">Physiotherapie</a>
    <nav>
        <a href="index.html">Start</a>
        <a href="">Leistungen</a>
        <a href="">Kontakt</a>
        <a href="">Anfahrt</a>
        <a href="">Impressum</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```